# Lot of trouble understanding holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

I am having a lot of difficulty understanding what is meant to be holomorphic and how to even show. For example, I was asked to show that $$f(z)=\sin(z)-\frac{z^2}{z+1}$$ is holomorphic wherever it is defined. I will show you what I did try and where my problems are.

I tried to break it into pieces and x and y I used that $$\sin(z)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\sinh(y)\cos(x)$$

and $$\frac{z^2}{z+1}=\frac{x^2-y^2+x^3+xy^2}{(1+x)^2+y^2}+i\frac{2xy+y^3+x^2y}{(1+x)^2+y^2}$$

but when I try to compute the CR and partial deravtives, I am getting extremely long and messy computations and it just doesn't seem right.

I also know that holomorphic is equivalent to having the partial deravtive with respect to z conjugate being zero. Or having a deravtive at all places.

I'm really lost and looking  for advice

Comment: It is well known that the trigonometric functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ as well as the rational functions are holomorphic (the rationals of course only where they are defined). Additionally, the sum of holomorphic functions is holomorphic. This is enough to show that your function is holomorphic.

Comment: Forget about $x,y$ and show instead that as $z \to z_0$ : $\sin(z) = \sin(z_0) + (z-z_0)\sin'(z_0)+ o(|z-z_0|)$ stays true for $z,z_0$ complex. Do the same for $\frac{z^2}{z+1}$, and voila

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\sin z$ is holomorphic everywhere, and so is $z^2$. On any disk that fails to contain $-1$, the function $1/(z+1)$ is also holomorphic (one can show directly that its derivative is $-1/(z+1)^2$.

Sums and products of holomorphic functions are again holomorphic, so $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Thanks and showing that its derivative exists is equivalent to  showing holomorphic? My other concern is, to find deravtive, how can we know we really tried all paths? I get that if we find one path even that doesn't work, then we can stop, but how to we have tried them all?

Answer (score 0):

An advice:

If $f,g$ are holomorphic then so are $f\cdot g$ and $f+g$.